# Python: xpath unable to find element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to get the text for features companies from a link. I inspect it and get the xpath but it is unable to find the element. The links is always change but it has a similarity with ended with `listedcompanies.com`

[image]

The text I want to scrape is highlighted in the screenshot.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.shareinvestor.com/my")
time.sleep(20)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@href='http://salcon.listedcompany.com']")
```

The error is

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@href=\'http://salcon.listedcompany.com\']"}' ; Stacktrace:
```

I want to get the text for those companies

Comment: What if you wait a second between getting the webpage and finding an element (with `time.sleep(1)` for instance)?

Comment: listedcompany.com this is what i can find and not salcon.listedcompany.com, are you sure its not getting generated after some button click or dynamically

Comment: @Exprator the screen for feature companies always change. I just want text from listedcompany.com.whenver it shown I will edit my post

Comment: ok then you need to put the timing like that, count the number of seconds the screen is coming put it inside sleep, then use xpath, because xpath wont scrape until the value is visible

Comment: @Exprator I just want to scrape the features companies show in the webite, no matter which companies.Please advise of the xpath. Thanks

Comment: sic_scrollPane take this class and you will get all the rotating companies, then you can take whatever  you want to take

Comment: @Exprator can you advise in the answer. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144719/discussion-between-behappy-and-exprator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need text below `Featured Companies` tab you can use this code:

```
import requests
from parsel import Selector

url = 'https://www.shareinvestor.com/my'
r = requests.get(url)
sel = Selector(r.text)
all_text = sel.xpath('//div[@class="sic_scrollPane" and a[img]]')
for ind, text in enumerate(all_text, start=1):
    text = ''.join(text.xpath('p//text()').extract())
    print(ind, text)
```

It gets you all text from that tab without the use of Selenium.

Note: I use [Parsel](https://parsel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#getting-started) library built on top of the lxml, but you can use `bs4` or `lxml`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `"//a[contains(@href, 'listedcompany.com')]"` `XPath` to match all links with `href` attribute that contains `"listedcompany.com"` as below:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://www.shareinvestor.com/my")
time.sleep(20)
lint_text_list = [link.text for link in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'listedcompany.com')]") if link.text]
```